# how to add several options to the package?

Tags: luatex

Is it possible to do several options in the package,for example that user of my package can do like that: `\usepackage[option1][option2=true]{mypackage}`. If it possible, give me please a little example which shows, how it works. I need exactly in several options because it should be set only once by users of my package and it should work only in the preamble of the document. I don't know, how to do this using commands and in my opinion, using options it the best way for this. If it is impossible to use several options in the package, help me please how to do the same using commands, I mean how to create command, which will work only in the preamble of the document, and which user can call only once? Thanks, everybody for any help.

Comment: You are mixing a number of questions (many options, how to set an option only once). Many options are giving by using commas, \usepackage[option1,option2]{mypackage}. But in general I think using a setup command is better.

Comment: Add your MWE, so we can see the real problem

Comment: @Ulrike-Fischer Ok,if it's possible use several options in the package,can you please give me an example,how to do this,for example that if the second option option1 is true,input this in log and in termenal. I want to implement it in our package and i will do it myself,if you will do the very small example for me. Thanks.

Comment: options differ for each package--which package are you referring to?

Comment: @js bibra For example simple mypackage with first string option and the second boolean option.

Comment: not understood-- what is the output finally that you desire-- can you insert a screeenshot or  hand drawn sketch of the output

Comment: What's wrong with form such as `\usepackage[opt1=doublespace,opt2=true]{mypackage}`? If you're concerned about wanting to call the package with just one or the other option, you can give defaults for both in the package's code.

Comment: There are many different ways to write a package, and many different choices available for which helper packages you can use. As a result, there are many different ways to process and set options. Look for 'how to write a package', and look inside existing packages (the `.sty` files) that have options to see the different ways they do it.  A starting point might be: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Packages